# Jsp - accesing pdf - using URL- "save or open" window shows error when clicked

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, pdf, redirect

I have a pdf residing on an enternal webserver. I have a JSP in my application in which i have to access that pdf using a URL. I have the URL with me. The task is that, when that URL is accessed, the pdf should get downloaded.

I used the following code. It 'opens the save or open dialogue box' which is desired, but when i click to open the pdf it says, *adobe reader could not open 'pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged*. Are there any headers that i am missing here?

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <%
            String site = new String("http://chfvld/manuals/zseriessection12.pdf");
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=zseriessection12.pdf");
            response.setHeader("Location", site);   
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a redirect on the other site:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
response.setStatus(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
response.setHeader("Location", "http://chfvld/manuals/zseriessection12.pdf");   
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Web browser is capable to understand that you are returning status code 301 (moved permanently) and will go to the location you defined. 
But if you do not want to expose internal web server to users that access your JSP, you will have to create a small proxy that will do the trick and grab the PDF.

Here is a small example with JSP that  Apache Commons HTTP client. I did not try it and it might not work, but you will get the idea...
Note: i recommend you do it in servlet, not in JSP, because scriptlets in JSP's are generally a bad design).

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,org.apache.commons.httpclient.*,org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://chfvld/manuals/zseriessection12.pdf");
try {
  // Execute the method.
  int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
  if (statusCode != javax.servlet.http.HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    response.setStatus(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  } else {
      // Read the response body.
      byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
      response.setContentType("application/pdf");
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=zseriessection12.pdf");
      response.getOutputStream().write(responseBody);
} catch (Exception e) {
  response.setStatus(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
} finally {
  // Release the connection.
  method.releaseConnection();
}  
%>
</body>
</html>
```